# Do we have terraform resource to create "google bigquery sink v2" kafka connector

Tags: confluent-cloud, google-bigquery-storage-api

Do we have terraform resource to create "google bigquery sink v2" kafka connector for writing kafka topics to bigquery. Or If there's any other way to automate this process?

I searched for confluent docs and terraform docs Nowhere it is mentioned for this connector.
https://github.com/confluentinc/terraform-provider-confluent/blob/master/examples/configurations/connectors

Can I use https://registry.terraform.io/providers/confluentinc/confluent/latest/docs/resources/confluent_custom_connector_plugin

for the same?